# Store arbitrary strings in sassscript variables?

Tags: sass

Is it possible to render arbitrary strings in scss? You can render property values:

```
/*source scss*/
$some-color: #123456;
a {color: $some-color;}

/*compiled css*/
a {color: #123456;}
```

or selectors/property names using [`#{}` interpolation syntax](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
/*source scss*/
$some-class: 'my-awesome-link';
$some-attribute: border;
a.#{$some-class} {#{$some-attribute}-color: #000;}

/*compiled css*/
a.my-awesome-link {border-color: #000;}
```

but I can't use the following:

```
/*source scss*/
$some-css: 'text-decoration:none;color:#000';
a {$some-css}  //breaks
a {#{$some-css}}  //breaks
```

This seems like vanilla string processing and something extremely trivial to allow. Am I overlooking a different syntax, or is it not possible in current scss?

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to do this over using a mixin?

Comment: @cimmanon: I'm using sass variables for stylesheet customization, and sometimes property combinations cannot be easily abstracted. How would I do this with a mixin? Again, just want to render a css string verbatim.

Comment: It sounds like you're approaching the problem wrong if this is intended to be a reusable library of some sort.  It would be better to use `@content` aware mixins or to simply have mixins you intend to overwrite.  I wouldn't even consider doing it that way if this is for theming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can get to what you want is like this:

```
@mixin property-list($list) {
    @each $i in $list {
        #{nth($i, 1)}: nth($i, 2);
    }
}

$links: color red, border (1px solid);

a {
    @include property-list($links);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
a {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```